Jest config file is not ignoring files correctly from testPathIgnorePatterns
I have this jest.config.ts file:
import coverageConfig from '../../jest.coverage.config';

/* eslint-disable */
export default {
  displayName: 'domain-handler',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/domain-handler',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': [
      'jest-preset-angular',
      {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
        stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      },
    ],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/pages',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/test_data',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/util',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/configs/grid',
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/pages',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/test_data',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/util',
    '<rootDir>/src/lib/configs/grid',
  ],
  ...coverageConfig,
};


also this is the content of coverageConfig:
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const coverageConfig: Config = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      statements: 90,
    },
  },
};

export default coverageConfig;

but neither testPathIgnorePatterns or coveragePathIgnorePatterns are working properly, both of them aren't ignoring test_data directory, util and configs/grid but its ignoring correctly pages.
The 4 directories have the same path:
workspace\ABC\PROJECT.UI\libs\domain-handler\src\lib\test_data
workspace\ABC\PROJECT.UI\libs\domain-handler\src\lib\pages
workspace\ABC\PROJECT.UI\libs\domain-handler\src\lib\configs
workspace\ABC\PROJECT.UI\libs\domain-handler\src\lib\util
I've tried doing jest --cleanCache and a few more things but nothing seems to work, any idea why?
Jest version is 18.0.8

Place a trailing slash after the directory: '<rootDir>/src/lib/pages/'

@SamScholefield thats not working neither

Could there be something in the coverageConfig file thats overriding the things you define in this file?

@SamScholefield i have updated the question with the content of coverageConfig
